# Copy Data Source From Between Visual Studio Projects

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to copy a Data Source between two Visual Studio VB.NET projects.  I have determined that, if I copy these files from the source project to the destination project:

1. ClassDiagram1.cd
2. DataSet1.Designer.vb
3. DataSet1.vb
4. DataSet1.xsc
5. DataSet1.xsd
6. DataSet1.xss

Then copy all of the entries like below from the source .vbproj into the *correct places* in the destination .vbproj file (using a text editor, not VS):

```
<Compile Include="DataSet1.Designer.vb">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>DataSet1.xsd</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="DataSet1.vb">
  <DependentUpon>DataSet1.xsd</DependentUpon>
</Compile>

<None Include="DataSet1.xsc">
  <DependentUpon>DataSet1.xsd</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="DataSet1.xsd">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSDataSetGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>DataSet1.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
</None>
<None Include="DataSet1.xss">
  <DependentUpon>DataSet1.xsd</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

The data source will magically appear when the destination project is next opened in VS.  My question is: Isn't there an easier way to do this?!?!?!  You'd think you'd be able to import the .xsd file or something, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: If the projects are in the same solution then you should just be able to drag the `DataSet` item from one to the other in the Solution Explorer. If they are in different solutions then you should be able to use *Add > Exiting Item* and and just select the top-level item (the XSD I think) and VS will bring the rest along for the ride.

Comment: It's definitely the .XSD.  That was almost too easy.  You want to make that the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the projects are in the same solution then you should just be able to drag the `DataSet` item from one to the other in the *Solution Explorer*. If they are in different solutions then you should be able to use *Add > Existing Item* and just select the top-level item (the XSD file) and VS will bring the rest along for the ride.